# performSegueWithIdentifier failing, but segue exists

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Currently working on an application for inventory control. The application allows the user to use either manual entry of barcode data (or an HID-mode scanner) OR a SocketMobile scanner via Socket's API.

The app works wonderfully smooth with manual entry, but I am having an issue with a particular segue in the workflow for the scanner. Specifically, the application will crash upon attempting to perform a segue via "performSegueWithIdentifier". This particular segue has been built in the same way as all the other segues: by dragging from on ViewController on the storyboard to another. The identifier in this case is "mySegue" and it absolutely exists.

When the following line is called in the application, it crashes:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender:self)
```

and returns the following error in the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<productionLINK_Scanner.Manifest_PulledItems: 0x126e3c680>) has no segue with identifier 'mySegue''
```

The segue is a modal with all default settings. I have tried different names for the segue, restarting computer and Xcode, deleting the application from the test device and removing the Derived Data folder to no avail.

It is important to note that the segue will successfully perform if I place a button on the UI to call a function which will perform the segue programmatically. It is only within the conditional statement that determines if the segue should perform that the crash occurs.

The SocketScan API has a setDelegate() function to allow a ViewController to receive and respond to scanApi notifications. This view from which I am segueing is the second-tier or delegate by which, I mean that the initial view controller passes delegate status to the view controller I am attempting to segue FROM in order to allow it to respond according to scanApi notifications. This is done as follows:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "manifestToRepackContainer" {
        scanApi.setDelegate(RepackContainer())
    }
}
```

where RepackContainer is the controller for the view that we are segueing to.

However, after changing the prepareForSegue method to this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "manifestToRepackContainer" {
        scanApi.setDelegate(segue.destinationViewController as RepackContainer)
    }
}
```

everything works great. So, what is the difference between the two prepareForSegue approaches?

Comment: The second prepareForSegue is correct because it uses  segue.destinationViewController. This is an instance of a view controller - it is the one you are segueing to. In your first prepareForSegue, you are creating a new instance of a view controller. Granted, it is the same type of view controller (RepackContainer) as you are segueing to, but it is a different instance. It is not the instance you are segueing to.